# Question about adding two tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

I am trying to calculate $\sum \limits_{\pi \in S_3} f_{\pi(1)} \otimes f_{\pi(2)} \otimes f_{\pi(3)}$, where $S_3$ is the set of all permutations $\pi$ of $3$ objects.

I know that 
\begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{\pi \in S_3} f_{\pi(1)} \otimes f_{\pi(2)} \otimes f_{\pi(3)} &= f_1 \otimes f_2 \otimes f_3 + f_1 \otimes f_3 \otimes f_2 + f_2 \otimes f_1 \otimes f_3 \; + \\
& \quad \quad + \; f_2 \otimes f_3 \otimes f_1 + f_3 \otimes f_1 \otimes f_2 + f_3 \otimes f_2 \otimes f_1 \\
\end{align*}
but not I am not sure on how to add these together. Is it correct to say this is equal to $\left(2f_1 + 2f_2 + 2f_3 \right)^{\otimes 3}$ = $\left(2f_1 + 2f_2 + 2f_3 \right) \otimes \left(2f_1 + 2f_2 + 2f_3 \right) \otimes \left(2f_1 + 2f_2 + 2f_3 \right)$?

Answer (score 1):

The tensor product distributes over addition, so your final expression is not equivalent to the sum you started with - it would have non-vanishing summands of the form $f_1 \otimes f_1 \otimes f_1$. There's really no simpler expression (in terms of the tensor product) than your displayed equation. It would sometimes be written as $3!\operatorname{Sym}(f_1 \otimes f_2 \otimes f_3)$, where $\operatorname{Sym}$ denotes taking the symmetric part of a tensor.